# How to create website shortcut in a VS Setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project, shortcut

How do I create a shortcut to my website in the VS 2008 Setup project?

I'd like to have a shortcut created inside User's Program Menu\MyProgram , after the application is installed.

I could create a shortcut to the application itself but I have no idea how to make a shortcut to an http:// address.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answser.

Create a .cmd file with:

start http://www.mywebsite.com

And add a shortcut to it.